# How can i use my extention from old theme in my new theme in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I had purchased and installed a search autocomplete extension in my old theme. I recently changed my theme. How can i use the same extension in my new theme.

Answer (score 1):

In order get this,you need some study about magento module structure.

You need to checkout below tutorials:

- [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/basic-folder-structure-for-new-magento-module/)
- [Magento Commerce tutorial](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Create+a+custom+module+with+a+custom+database+table)

Basically you need to copy [assume that your module name is X]

- your module main configuration from  `app/etc/modules`
- Your module from `app/code/[MOdule_CodePOOL]/`

In my concept,as your extension is on **search autocomplete**   that mean there may be `some layout files,phtml files, and js exits,`.

**layout files you can find at**

*app/design/frontent/Your_pacakage/Yourthene folder/layout*

*or app/design/frontend/base/default/layout*

**template files you can find at**

*app/design/frontend/Your_package/Yourtheme folder/template*

*or app/design/frontent/base/default/template*

**js files you can find at at**

*skin/frontend/Your_pacakage/Yourtheme folder/*

*or js*